# IMPORTXML from Etsy- 'Imported Content is Empty' error

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I built a spreadsheet to keep track of the daily sales in my Etsy shop and had successfully pulled the live number through an ImportXML formula. This week, the formula suddenly began to return an 'Imported content is empty' error and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

I'm trying to scrape the number where it says "337 Sales" at the top of [this page](https://www.etsy.com/shop/LMNOprints).

Previously, I had successfully used

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.etsy.com/shop/lmnoprints", "//span[@class='shop-sales hide-border no-wrap']")
```

But it seems that Etsy has since updated some things and that Xpath no longer exists. Now I have tried

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.etsy.com/shop/lmnoprints", "//span[@class='wt-text-body-01 no-wrap']")
```

...but I'm still getting the same error message. Can anyone point out any dumb mistakes I'm making? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received help for this through Reddit! Posting to help anyone else having this issue:

```
=index(importxml("https://www.etsy.com/shop/LMNOprints","//span[@class='wt-text-caption wt-no-wrap']"),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the url based on this [link](https://www.etsy.com/shop/LMNOprints)

**Use:**

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.etsy.com/shop/LMNOprints", "//span[@class='wt-text-body-01 no-wrap']")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Ron! I'm getting inconsistent results with this somehow. It worked the first time I entered it, then I changed the shop name in the URL to test it on my other shop. I got the same error message, then clicked undo only to find the error message still there. [Screenshot here for example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dtr2v0V3Rd7NRjhoqzaBlGD8W0v3SVHV/view?usp=sharing).